# Short story from an anthology book where a man travels back in time trying to meet Jesus but ends up becoming him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

This story involved a young man in the future who travels back to the time of Jesus to meet him only to end up as Jesus.  He is able to perform "miracles" because he shares some aspirin from his pocket with a sick person, he is aware of future events, etc.

This story has haunted me for the past 30 years.  I cannot seem to find the anthology book that it was in although I purchased the book in paperback form and it was anytime from 1983-1986.

It is not "Let's Go to Gologtha".

Comment: And it's not "Behold the Man"? https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_166v50_1966-09

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AdventuresInTheBible

Comment: And it’s not “The Skull” by Phillip K. Dick? https://www.gutenberg.org/files/30255/30255-h/30255-h.htm

Comment: it would be nice to read a science fiction story involving time travel where the main character occasionally *doesn't* turn out to be Jesus

Comment: There's _Live From Golgotha_ by Gore Vidal but that's a full novel and doesn't involve aspirin.

Comment: @Valorum - or adam/eve.

Comment: I remember this story. It was in Heavy Metal magazine as a short one-shot comic.
I'm also trying to figure out what the name of it is so that I can re-read it. It's been years. IIRC the issue it was in is from the 80s and has a typical HM-style busty barbarian woman on the cover riding a dragon or something.

Comment: @dummydumdum - Trying to find a Heavy Metal cover with a busty sword-wielding maiden is like trying to find straw in a haystack.

Comment: For HM covers, check this site.... http://subscriptions.heavymetal.com/cover.php

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure it’s not Michael Moorcock’s 1966 novella, **Behold the Man**? ‘Cause it sure sounds like it. Moorcock expanded it into a novel in 1969, but you would’ve read the novella if it was in an anthology. The protagonist is obsessed with Jesus, travels back and discovers that Mary’s son is pretty much a drooling idiot, so he performs all the stuff that Jesus is said to have done, and ends up being crucified. It’s been a long time since I read it, but if I remember correctly, he reasons that he *has* to be crucified in order to kickstart Christianity.

Comment: That novella was indeed anthologized, this ISFDB page lists anthologies and collections in which it appeared: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41617 You can refresh your memory by rereading the story at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_166v50_1966-09